# Is it considered bad practice to return strings for functions you would typically return void?

Tags: java

```
class Main {

  public static int total = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    addToTotal(5);
    addToTotal(199);
    System.out.println(addToTotal(1));
  }

  public static String addToTotal(int amount){
    total += amount;
    return "Successfully added " + amount + " to total for result of " + total;
  }
}
```

For instance, take this program that adds to the class total. It normally wouldn't need a return statement - but to me it seems like having it return a string for what happened seems like it would help with debugging complex problems. Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Consider logging that instead.

Comment: Debugging stuff is done with a java debugger tool. You may find it useful to give a try to different java debuggers available out there, and also about differeng logging techniques to decide which best suits your needs. But if the class is expected to implement business logic, it is usually better to user loggers or debuggers instead of hardcoded solutions ( System.out and/or method parameters or method return types designed) for logging and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods should complete the action their name describes.

If you start doing this, a programmer may start using the returned Strings for reasons other than debugging, and the spaghetti code strand will begin.

Always keep code as simple as you can. What you're trying to describe here is trace logging.

[SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is a great logging facade for Java because it allows you to implement multiple logging services at run-time. Here is an example of the usage in code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class Main {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
  public static int total = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    addToTotal(5);
    addToTotal(199);
    System.out.println(addToTotal(1));
  }

  public static void addToTotal(int amount){
    total += amount;

    log.trace("Successfully added " + amount + " to total for result of " + total);
  }
}
```

With a logger service configured, you can make the output go to anywhere you choose. Common outputs are the console out, a file, event viewer in Windows or syslog in Linux, a logging web app or even a Slack or Discord webhook. (Though you wouldnt want to be sending trace logs to Slack or Discord.)

Comment: You're right. Even says so in its name. How could I do it wrong like that.

Comment: `log.repent("I'm sorry")`

Comment: For simplicity, I didn't use parametrized logging. But @Michael 's answer shows an example of that kind of log statement, and it is better for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, bad practice. What happens if you want to return a value and also add a debug statement? You can't do both.

You are also taking the performance hit of string concatenation even when it is unused. A clever optimizer might be able to optimize that away but I wouldn't count on it.

[Parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) is what you should be using. It will only perform the concatenation if it is actually required. IMO it is more readable too.

```
public static void addToTotal(int amount){
    total += amount;
    log.trace("Successfully added {} to total for result of {}", amount, total);
}
```

Comment: I think performance is the least of the issues here. It's a major design flaw to return Strings (and only from normally void methods) for possible debugging purposes. Considering performance here is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Kayaman "*It's a major design flaw to return Strings (and only from normally void methods) for possible debugging purposes*" I agree conceptually but try explaining concisely why that should be true. [`Collection.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) returns a boolean to say whether anything was actually added. IMO that is conceptually the exact same design flaw (albeit slightly more performant), and that was written by revered Java expert Josh Bloch...

Comment: I do not share that opinion. It's not debug information, it's a result of the method call (saving an extra explicit check from you). Performance is a sad magic word that gets people excited, so they'll gladly exchange irrelevant micro-optimization for proper design. That doesn't result in performant code *or* good code, which is why I lament every time performance is discussed in questions where performance is not relevant. 20 years ago when I started writing Java there were reasons to try to squeeze out extra perf, now we've got enormous CPU power.

Comment: @Kayaman I didn't say the bool was debug information. Both methods return extra things that are not required simply because "hey, might be convenient" and both are bad for that reason. A method that returns a boolean should start with 'is'. I should be able to write `if (thing.isFoo())` and have that be idiomatic. `if (coll.addAll(coll2))` is a load of gibberish and requires me to check the JavaDoc to see what the boolean means or memorize it. I'm 100% with you about performance, but the kind of design he is suggesting is actually not that far from what is prevalent across the whole JDK.

Comment: A **getter** that returns a boolean starts with `is` (per the JavaBean spec). A method that returns a `String` for debug information is bad design. A builder class that returns `this` from setters is a [fluent builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). You're confusing things and I don't really know what your angle is, but I'm going to stop this conversation since I'm too old for this...discussion.

Comment: @Kayaman The JavaBean spec is trash which encourages mutability and classes as behaviourless bags of data. Why do you mention it? "*A method that returns a String for debug information is bad design*" I have repeatedly said I agree with this ("both are bad"), I'm just saying that I empathetise with OP's feeling that this may be an acceptable design since there are equally bad things in the same spirit which we use every day.

Comment: I think this would be better to discuss in chat. 
On topic: I agree parametrized logging is more efficient, but I didn't include it in my answer since I feel introducing OP to logging is more important than introducing optimizations. But I feel this answer adds some depth and is useful. Thanks Michael!